# Qiskit: Extract individual Pauli strings from a PauliSumOp

Tags: qiskit

Suppose I have a `PauliSumOp` as follows:

```
from qiskit.opflow import X, Z, I, Y

h = (X ^ X ^ I) + (I ^ Y ^ Y) + (Z ^ Z ^ X)
```

I would like to go over the Pauli strings and do something with each string (for example, I need to know the positions of nontrivial Pauli matrices, but that's beside the point). I can iterate over `h`:

```
for k in h:
    ...
```

In this case, `k` will be a `PauliSumOp` with one Pauli string and one weight. The trouble is, I can't understand how to get the string itself (for example as a `str`, but a `PauliOp` will also do).

Is there a recommended way to extract individual Pauli strings from a `PauliSumOp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `PauliSumOp` into `PauliOp` with [`to_pauli_op`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.PauliSumOp.to_pauli_op.html).

```
from qiskit.opflow import X, Z, I, Y

h = (X ^ X ^ I) + (I ^ Y ^ Y) + (Z ^ Z ^ X)
for k in h.to_pauli_op():
    print(k)
```

```
XXI
IYY
ZZX
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow overlooked that PauliSumOp has this function.